# How can I map specific props to state?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, state

I'm trying to map specific props to the `brands` state. Also, don't add values that already exist in the `brands` state.

Goal output:

```
brands: [
  "IKEA",
  "Tesla"
]
```

My attempt

```
const mapState = (state) => ({
  brands: state.products.forEach(product => {
    if (product.brands) {
      return product.brands;
    }
  })
});

export default connect(mapState)(Brands);
```

State:

```
products: [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Pen",
    "brands": "IKEA"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Flamethrower",
    "brands": "Tesla"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "T-shirt",
    "brands": "Tesla"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` does not return anything. What you could do is create a function `getAllProductBrands` and call this function. This function should then return a list of all brands.

```
const getAllProductBrands = (products) => {
  const brands = [];
  products.forEach(product => {
    if(!brands.some(brand => brand === product.brand) {
      brands = [...brands, product.brand];    
    };
  });
};
```

You can then call this function in your mapState.

```
const mapState = (state) => ({
  brands: getAllProductBrands(state.products)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following by using `.reduce`[1] to build up an array of distinct products.

```js
const mapState = (state) => ({
  brands: state
     .products
     .reduce((brands, product) => {
        if (!brands.includes(product.brands)) {
           return brands.concat([product.brands]);
        }
        return brands;
     }, [])
  })
});

export default connect(mapState)(Brands);
```

You can extract retrieving distinct brands into a function if you need to reuse this in your application:

```js
function getProductBrands(products) {
   return products
     .reduce((brands, product) => {
        if (!brands.includes(product.brands)) {
           return brands.concat([product.brands]);
        }
        return brands;
     }, []);
}
```

References:
[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Thanks, it worked just fine. Is there any way to return an object instead of strings like this `[{brand: IKEA, products: 1}, {brand: Tesla, products: 2}]`?

Comment: Sure.. https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-chaplygin-vfvz9?file=/src/index.js, works a bit different as you need a way to count the brands.

Comment: I don't understand how I can do it inside map state function

Comment: You can either copy the function into your file and do `brands: getProductBrands(state.products)` inside your map state function or put it in another file and import it into your file, i.e. `import { getProductBrands } from "../utils/product.js"`

Answer (score 1):

To get list of brands uniquely

```js
const mapState = ({products}) => {
  const brands = [...new Set( products
     .map(product => product.brands))];
  return { brands }
};
```